# What is the behavior of the & operator when comparing a list and an integer in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently exploring a method that I haven't written myself that has the following code in a method:

```py
if (self.some_list & 3):
   #do something
```

What is the purpose of this expression? I can't seem to find an answer online.

Comment: Are you asking what is bitwise and?

Comment: @Sayse yes, that's what I'm asking about

Comment: You *can't* use `&` on a list.  Either `self.some_list` is some other data type (a Numpy array, perhaps), or the code is simply broken.